# How can I add overlay images or text on top of videos in Android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, overlay, media

I'm trying to add overlay images/text on top of mp4 videos inside an Android application. 
Most solutions point to FFmpeg (or appunits AndroidFFmpeg) but isn't stable and very complicated to maintain. 
Is there a native way to do this using the Android SDK? (MediaCodec? MediaMuxer?)

Thank you, 
Ori

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to understand your question:

1. **You want to temporarily superimpose video with additional information**.
   This can be done using the standard layout procedure:

Use the built-in [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html). You might need to wrap the textView /imageView in an additional layout to push it to the front:

```
 <VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:background="#00000000"/>
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Text"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

2. **You want to add the additional information to the video itself.**
   This is obviously much more difficult. You could use [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html) for this. For information on OpenCV+Android visit [their website](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html).

**Update:** As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23326865/1531708), the [ExtractMpegFramesTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest) might be interesting for you

Comment: Hi PhiLab, #2 is the relevant solution. 
I'm trying to edit the video file itself. I will try to work with OpenCV and update the thread. Thanks!

Comment: you almost certainly just use FFMPEG for this these days, 2017