# Is it possible to get GLES texture from Canvas or Surface?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, surfaceview

I trying to use `Canvas` from such methods:

```
 Canvas mCanvas = mSurface.lockCanvas(null);   
 mSurface.unlockCanvasAndPost(mCanvas);
```

I need to display images or text on camera preview. The way I choose is to create texture from `canvas`, which contains views. I gonna combine this texture and texture of video frame. Is it right way?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914448/how-can-i-add-overlay-images-or-text-on-top-of-videos-in-android

Comment: @MorrisonChang , I've edit question, thanks! As 'video' I mean a GlSurfaceView which handle frames from camera and recording video file. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be much harder than making a texture in OpenGL.

```
  Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  this.draw(canvas); 
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/texture.png");
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(file));
```

Technically, a Bitmap file or each camera frame is not a texture. To make them textures, you should call a gl function like gltex****(,,,**bitmap**);