# Android ImageReader analogue in api 16-18

Tags: android, image, rendering, android-mediacodec

I would like to render image using MediaCodec on Android API 16. Now I have a working solution for API 19+ which looks like that:

```
ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(800, 600, fmt, 1);
MediaCodec decoder = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(decoderName);

//...

decoder.configure(inputFormat, reader.getSurface(), null, 0);

//call decoder.start(), queue buffer, etc. ...
Image image = reader.acquireNextImage();

Bitmap result = convertImage(image);
```

So the question is: what should I do to achieve such functionality (even with the loss of speed/performance) using API 16-18?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321880/how-to-get-bitmap-frames-from-video-using-mediacodec

Comment: @TomerNuni, thanks. Seems that links provided in answer to that question contains needed information. I'll check it within a couple of days.